# What song is playing in Naruto Shippuden episode 114 at 06:37 on Orochimaru's flashback?

Tags: naruto, music

There's a song playing in *Naruto Shippuden* episode 114 at 06:37.

This is the flashback scene focusing on Orochimaru, where he watches Itachi and is impressed by the power of the Uchiha, ponders about the length of time it would take to master all the Jutsu in the world, ponders about the limited lifespan of humans, and gets caught by Sarutobi doing shady things.

What is that song?

Answer (score 1):

It appears an unreleased track (it's not in Shippuden Original Soundtrack 1, 2, or 3). There's an [unofficial imperfect spliced version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U21MgQMLsKY) though, titled "Six paths of pain / Given Judgment".

Additional notes:

- This also plays in Shippuden episode 79 (starting at 13:56), when Hidan stabs Asuma.
- This also plays in Shippuden episode 117 (starting at 11:42), when they're going to the Northen hideout to fetch Juufo and they're fighting against all the Stage 2 curse mark prisoners running amok.
- This also plays in Shippuden episode 211 (starting at ~8:01), near the end of the Danzo vs. Sasuke fight, when Danzo finally unwraps the bandages on his face and reveals his hidden eye.
- This also plays in Shippuden episode 251 (starting at 1:02), after the third Gai vs. Kisame fight at Island Turtle, when Gai says "Don't move" while standing above Kisame.